# Does babel get used by default when deploying a React app?

Tags: reactjs, npm, babeljs

I am trying to figure out how Babel gets used.

In one of my current projects, I see that I have a Babel file, but I never set up any configuration as far as I can tell that deals with Babel. So I want to know if it is actually being used or if I just have it installed.

When I deploy my React app to somewhere like AWS Amplify or Heroku, is Babel automatically being used and this is how my browser can understand React? Or would my browser understand React even without Babel?

Comment: We don't know. Probably? Create React App apps certainly use Babel, on the default JS template at least. If you're using JSX that will definitely need to be converted to regular JS syntax _somehow_, but that can also be done by e.g. the TypeScript compiler. Some of the other syntax you're using may also need transpiling for wider browser support.

Comment: I am using JSX and dont think I am using TypeScript, so I guess its safe to assume that Babel is in effect? I guess my real question is, is there any additional configuration to Babel to make it work after installing or does it 'just work'?

Answer (score 0):

You can not be sure that all versions of all browsers understand modern JavaScript. That is why, even if you write modern JS in your code, Babel will automatically turn it to plain vanilla JS so that it is compatible with almost every browsers.

This links I attached below, are of highlighted texts. Please give it a read as I believe it will clear up your confusions somewhat.

[https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/jsx-in-react-introduction/#:~:text=But%20the%20browser,JavaScript%20compiler/transpiler](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/jsx-in-react-introduction/#:%7E:text=But%20the%20browser,JavaScript%20compiler/transpiler).

[https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/#:~:text=You%20don%E2%80%99t%20need,good%20to%20go](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/#:%7E:text=You%20don%E2%80%99t%20need,good%20to%20go).